# url link to activate a javascript function once the page has loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a page where various javascript functions shows different part of an array.

The code I use to select what information to display is:

```
<a href="#" onClick="x(ncode1);">
<a href="#" onClick="x(ncode2);">
```

Clicking the a tag will activate the function x(ncode).  The page default loads to x(ncode1).   When x(ncode2) is activated, the url naturally changes to site.com/#

If I want to make a link direct to the x(ncode2) display, I understand I need to link to the page and activate the javascript function once the page has loaded.  How so I do this?

Comment: You mean like `site.com/#ncode2`? Use `document.location.hash` and the `hashchange` event on `window`.

Comment: site.com/#x(ncode2)doesnt do anything, as I need to activate the javascript function for the data to change.

Comment: do you mean I should code the js so site.com/#ncode2 activates the function?  Could you give an example?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on Halcyon this code works:

If the page is site.com/#2 run function x(ncode2) after the page has loaded

```
window.onload = function() {
 if(window.location.hash == "#2"){
         x(ncode2);   
 }
};
```